# firebase python admin create user has no module

Tags: python, firebase

I want to create user with firebase admin in python but getting this error

Here is my code

https://github.com/firebase

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import auth
from firebase_admin import credentials
cred = credentials.Certificate('/var/www/html/core-python/44639adf86.json')

default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
print(default_app.name)

user = firebase_admin.auth.create_user(
    email='user@example.com',
    email_verified=False,
    phone_number='+15555550100',
    password='secretPassword',
    display_name='John Doe',
    photo_url='http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png',
    disabled=False)
```

output

```
[DEFAULT]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import.py", line 9, in <module>
    user = firebase_admin.auth.create_user(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'create_user'
```

Comment: Try to change it to `user = auth.create_user`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try like this

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import auth
from firebase_admin import credentials
cred = credentials.Certificate('/var/www/html/core-python/44639adf86.json')


default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
print(default_app.name)


user = auth.create_user(
    email='user@example.com',
    email_verified=False,
    phone_number='+15555550100',
    password='secretPassword',
    display_name='John Doe',
    photo_url='http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png',
    disabled=False)
```

remove the firebase_admin that you have given, because you have already imported auth, so no need to call `firebase.admin.auth` again

Comment: you are so late

Comment: sorry, i saw this post recently and i'm new to this